# How to use weak_ptr in tbb::concurrent_unordered_map?

Tags: c++, tbb, weak-ptr

I am using `tbb::concurrent_unordered_map` to replace `std::map` in my program like this:

```
Before:

class KvSubTable;
typedef std::weak_ptr<KvSubTable> KvSubTableId;
std::map<KvSubTableId, int, std::owner_less<KvSubTableId> > mEntryMap;
```

Now, I use `tbb::concurrent_unordered_map` to replace `std::map` , but it has some compile errors:

```
tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<KvSubTableId, int, tbb::tbb_hash<KvSubTableId>, std::owner_less<KvSubTableId> > mEntryMap;
```

> cpp/ext/amd64/include/tbb/internal/_tbb_hash_compare_impl.h:66:37:
>   error: invalid static_cast from type 'const
>   std::weak_ptr' to type 'std::size_t
>   {aka long unsigned int}'
>   return static_cast( t ) * internal::hash_multiplier;

I have try some solutions like this , but it does not work:

```
template <typename T>
inline bool operator==(const std::weak_ptr<T>& t, const std::weak_ptr<T>& u)
{
    return !t.owner_before(u) && !u.owner_before(t);
}
```

So, how can it work, please help....

Comment: **Unordered** map is not map and requires a hash function. You should also provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a hash function for `std::weak_ptr`. You can find [the example](https://github.com/01org/tbb/blob/b9805bacadd4d0474fd3358cf0c7153042ce50c3/src/test/test_concurrent_unordered_common.h#L709-L734) in tests for the TBB library.